# HTML5 and File API in Chrome problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to get this piece of code work in Chrome (latest build 10.0.648.205) and it works as expected in Firefox. Here, the e.target.result of the showImage function is empty. Can anyone tell me what Am I doing wrong?

```
$(function () {

    var dropbox = document.getElementById("dropimage");

    dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", function (e) {
        this.className = "over";
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }, false);

    dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();
    }, false);

    dropbox.addEventListener("dragleave", function (e) {
        var target = e.target;

        if (e && e === dropbox) {
            this.className = "";
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }, false);

    dropbox.addEventListener("drop", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
        var count = files.length;

        if (count > 0) {
            handleFiles(files)
        }
    }, false);

    function handleFiles(files) {
        $("#droplabel").html("Processing...");

        file = files[0];

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = showImage;        
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function showImage(e) {
        $("#playerImage").attr("src", e.target.result);
        $("#droplabel").html("Done");
    }
 });
```

HTML is straight-forward (I took the lines that include the scripts for simplicity):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img id="playerImage"/>
        <div id="dropimage">
            <span id="droplabel">Drop file here...</span>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Also, if I try to change the dropbox.addEventListener for jQuery's $.bind, it doesn't do anything at all. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was opening the html as a file. Chrome doesn't like that, so I resolved the problem by placing my html file in the **wwwroot** folder and opening it using a *localhost/dnd.html* address.